# Android Compose ModalBottomSheetLayout outside click

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-modifier, android-modalbottomsheetlayout

I want to catch event when user clicks outside of `ModalBottomSheetLayout`.
I wrapped `ModalBottomSheetLayout` with `Box` which is full size of the screen and set click listener. But Click listener only works when I click on the `ModalBottomSheetLayout` but not outside. I guess `ModalBottomSheetLayout` already consumes tap events and doesn't allow me to catch it?

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable {
            Log.e("TAG", "clicked!")
        }.pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures {
                Log.e("TAG", "tapped!")
            }
        }
        .fillMaxSize()
) {
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = sheetState,
        sheetContent = {
            content()
        }
    )
}
```

Is there a way to catch the event of `click`/`tap` outside of `ModalBottomSheetLayout`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ModalBottomSheetLayout api doesn't allow you to catch this events, but you can do the following:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .pointerInteropFilter {
            val bottomSheetShown = sheetState.currentValue != ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden
            val outside = it.y < sheetState.offset.value

            if (bottomSheetShown && outside) {
                // do you own logic here
                Log.d("BottomSheet", "MotionEvent outside")
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        }
) {
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetContent = { BottomSheetContent() },
        content = { Screen(onShow = { coroutineScope.launch { sheetState.show() } }) },
        sheetState = sheetState,
    )
}
```

This way you will get all the MotionEvents inside of the `if (bottomSheetShown && outside` block. There you can process this events, do you business and after that ether pass it forward to the bottom sheet (by returning `false`) or block it (by returning `true` - then your bottom sheet will not get this events)

Comment: pointerInteropFilter is what I needed! Thanks Dmitry!

Comment: Unfortunately, offset has been removed in new versions of compose

Answer (score 0):

```
LaunchedEffect(sheetState.currentValue) {
    if (sheetState.currentValue == ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden) {
       // Do work Here
    }
}

ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetContent = { BottomSheetContent() },
    content = { Screen(onShow = { coroutineScope.launch { sheetState.show() } }) },
    sheetState = sheetState,
)
```

Whenever there is change in state of modal bottom sheet it will be listen by launchedEffect and trigger the logic that you want to perform.